# Two form with submit button

Tags: php

I have two form with submit button in php file
when click on first submit button url become
http://url.com/?valueI=Want

when click second submit button: I need url become http://url.com/
without parameter

How i can do this please

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ASK_Button'])) {

}
if (isset($_POST['SET_Button'])) {

}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="ASKUser" class="blocks" action="#" method="post">
            <input type="submit" Name="ASK_Button" value="ASK">
        </form>

        <form id="SETUser" class="blocks" action="#" method="post">
            <input type="submit" Name="SET_Button" value="SET">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make your first form a GET method...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ask form method to GET

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ASK_Button'])) {

}
if (isset($_POST['SET_Button'])) {

}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="ASKUser" class="blocks" action="#" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="valuel" value="Want">
            <input type="submit" Name="ASK_Button" value="ASK">
        </form>

        <form id="SETUser" class="blocks" action="#" method="post">
            <input type="submit" Name="SET_Button" value="SET">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how I can set it when I need to set input value

Comment: @rababah in that case you will need to change the first form method to GET and add an input with the name "valuel"  I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

With use of action attribute. Set it how you need. Or change it in onSubmit form handler.